# How to append the Data from Top using PHP in Json file

Tags: php, jquery, json

I"m using php to append the data in Json file. It works correctly but it appends the data at the bottom. I want to add the data on the top ...such that user could see new data first.

Here is my php file

```html
<?php

$myFile = "news.json";
$arr_data = []; // create empty array

try {
    //Get form data
    $formdata = [
        'name'  => $_POST['name'],
        'price' => $_POST['price'],
    ];

    //Get data from existing json file
    $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);

    // converts json data into array
    $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    // Push user data to array
    array_push($arr_data, $formdata);

    //Convert updated array to JSON
    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    //write json data into data.json file
    if (file_put_contents($myFile, $jsondata)) {
        header("Location: index.html");
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

?>
```

and output json is

```html
[
    {
        "name": "Iphone X",
        "price": "$1500 "
    },
  
    {
        "name": "Play Station Console",
        "price": "$500 "
    }
]
```

Comment: Well that's what array_push does. Did you mean to use [array_unshift](http://php.net/array_unshift)?

Comment: @JonStirling yes exactly and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a simple "+"

see example below:

```
$a = [

    '1'=>2,
    '2'=>3
];
$b=[
    '3' => 4,
    '5' => 6
];

$c = $b + $a;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($c);
```

with result:

```
Array
(
    [3] => 4
    [5] => 6
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

in your case change:

```
array_push($arr_data,$formdata);
```

to

`$arr_data = $formdata + $arr_data`;

Hope it helps:)